# Unit test in Play Framework 2 (Java) not rolling back changes between tests

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean, transactional

I have a unit test where I would like to test that a certain runtime exception occurs. However, it seems that the database changes are not rolled back between each test in the test class, which is the normal behaviour (and works for all the other tests I have).

I have tried to create a minimal example of the problem which can be seen below. When running `TestTest` below you get a `Unique index or primary key violation` from the call to `MyClass.create("abc")` in the `setUp()` method when the second test is run.

The problem seems to require this specific setup: even the slightest change makes the problem disappear, e.g. if one interchanges the names of the two tests; if one tries to simplify some of the levels of methods calling methods etc.; or if one uses a class that is not an `@Entity` or a method that is not `@Transactional`.

I simply don't understand this. Can anyone help?

I am using Play Framework 2.2 (Java version).

The unit test class:

```
public class TestTest extends WithApplication {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        start(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase(), fakeGlobal()));
        MyClass.create("abc");
    }

    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void test1() {
        MyClass c = MyClass.create("blabla");
        c.foo();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        assert(true);
    }
}
```

The implementation of MyClass:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    public String name;

    private MyClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static MyClass create(String name) {
        MyClass c = new MyClass(name);
        c.save();
        return c;
    }

    @Transactional(type = TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void foo() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.foo();
    }

    class Bar {
        void foo() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the other tests also extend `WithApplication`?

Comment: Can you try without catching exceptions in the test? Tests shouldn't catch exceptions; all test runner frameworks are smart enough to fail tests which throw exceptions.

Comment: I have used try-catch because I want to test things AFTER the occurrence of the exception. However for this example, it is not important, so I have now tried without the try-catch and can confirm that the problem is still there. I have updated the text with this new setup.

Comment: The next thing for me would be to break out the debugger, set breakpoints in the transaction manager (especially places where `rollback()` and `commit()` are called) and run a test that works.

Answer (score 0):

Play does not do that. You have to manually rollback changes in database :(. In my projects, using ebean, I created a superclass that does this job for me. You can take a look in this gist => https://gist.github.com/asouza/1b415e5582c7b9fff9b0.

Comment: That sounds weird. If I remove the `expected = RuntimeException.class` and comment out the line `c.foo()` (which produces the RuntimeException) in the first test, then both tests pass. So it seems that the database changes are, in fact, rolled back when there is no RuntimeException along the way.